# Dropping a table in vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net

I want to create a table with an SQL query using vb.net. I use the following code:

```
dBaseConnection.Open()
sql = "DROP TABLE TagSubs;" &
      "CREATE TABLE TagSubs (TAGNAME varchar(79), POLLTIME varchar(6), SCALEMODE varchar(8), DEADBAND varchar(15))"
Dim dBaseCommand As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, dBaseConnection)
dBaseCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
dBaseCommand = Nothing
dBaseConnection.Close()
```

For some reason, if i omit the line:

```
 "DROP TABLE TagSubs;"
```

The application creates the table just fine, the first time. But the second time I execute it, it tells me the table already exists and throws up an error. That is why I added the drop table part.

Unfortunatly for me, this gives me a syntax error that applies to "DROP TABLE or DROP INDEX"

What am I doing wrong ?

---

Edit 1:

The error message I get is the following(roughly translated from dutch):

```
The instruction DROP TABLE or DROP INDEX contains a syntaxerror
```

And the only help that is given by visual studio is:

```
Get general help for this exception
```

Wich is not really any help at all!

---

Edit 2:

After the comments from Steve and Mitch, I have changed the code to:

```
sql = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TagSubs"
dBaseCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, dBaseConnection)
dBaseCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
dBaseCommand = Nothing

sql = "CREATE TABLE TagSubs (TAGNAME varchar(79), POLLTIME varchar(6), SCALEMODE varchar(8), DEADBAND varchar(15))"
dBaseCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, dBaseConnection)
dBaseCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
dBaseCommand = Nothing
dBaseConnection.Close()
```

However, this gives the error:

```
"An invalid SQL instruction was found. DELETE,INSERT, PROCEDURE, SELECT or UPDATE was expected"
```

Comment: check if it exists first....BTW: usually when tables are being droped they are temporary, or perhaps the code is not correct....

Comment: OleDb could be applied to a very different number of database engines. Which database are you working on? There are subtle differences in their SQL languages

Comment: Is it really a syntax error? What is the exact error message?

Comment: @Steve: I guess we may have a hint in the connection variable name: "dBase".

Comment: @MitchWheat I understand the code is not correct, if it was, I would not be here :P

Comment: @Guffa I have edited my question, I hope this information answers your question

Comment: @Gutanoth: I'm talking about the intent of the code; not your implementation

Comment: Supposing that this commands are not understood well when they are joined together, I will try to separate them executing two different commands, one to DROP and one to CREATE.

Comment: @MitchWheat and Steve I have updated my question to implement your suggestions combined

Comment: Which one gives the error?

Comment: @ Steve If i omit the part  " IF EXISTS" the code works like a charm, as long as the table already exists, if I try to create the tables in a folder where they are new, I get the error: The table DB_Total does not exist. So I think my IF EXISTS part, is wrong

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: @RemarkLima as stated before, I am using the dBase (III) format

Comment: @Gutanoth Sorry, I missed that! I'm not familiar with dBase but reading around it has a IDE / Interface like access right? If so, can you run the `DROP TABLE` command in the native interface? Does it work? Does it give you the same error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supposing that these commands are not well understood when they are joined together, I will try to separate them executing two different queries, then execute the two sql commands with two different runs.

The command to DROP the table should be executed only if the table exists. In DBF a table is normally contained in a simple Operating System File. So a check if the file exists should be enough.

```
dBaseConnection.Open()
Dim dBaseCommand As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand()
dBaseCommand.Connection = dBaseConnection
if File.Exists(... insert path here .... "\TagSubs.DBF") Then
    sql = "DROP TABLE TagSubs"
    dBaseCommand.CommandText = sql
    dBaseCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
End If
sql="CREATE TABLE TagSubs (TAGNAME varchar(79), POLLTIME varchar(6), SCALEMODE varchar(8), DEADBAND varchar(15))"
dBaseCommand.CommandText = sql
dBaseCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
dBaseCommand = Nothing
dBaseConnection.Close()
```

Comment: Am I right in thinking dBase III uses a seperate file per table?

Comment: @RemarkLima Yes you are right! The dBase III creates a seperate .dbf file for every table you create, In programs like CitectScada, you can import these files and link them

Comment: OK, I see the answer above works. Not sure, but you could also try deleting the `dbf` file directly - again, depends if dBase has a master table that tracks the files? Just a thought.

Comment: This is something worth trying, though I don't really know wether this will make a significant difference

Answer (score 0):

Try this one and put on your procedure to drop:

```
Dim rsSchema As ADODB.Recordset
rsSchema = New ADODB.Recordset

rsSchema = conn.OpenSchema(ADODB.SchemaEnum.adSchemaColumns, New Object() {Nothing, Nothing, **tablename**, Nothing})
'MsgBox(rsSchema)

If rsSchema.BOF And rsSchema.EOF Then
    MsgBox("Table does not exist")
Else
    MsgBox("Table exists")
End If
rsSchema.Close()
rsSchema = Nothing
```

Connection like this:

```
Public Sub modOpen()

    Msg = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1; Persist Security Info=False;" & Chr(10)
    Msg = Msg & "password=******;Data Source=**KOMPUTERNAME**;Initial Catalog=**DATABASENAME**;User ID=**USERID**"


    Try
        conn = New Adodb.Connection
        conn.ConnectionString = Msg

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error: " & ex.Source & ": " & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Connection Error!!")

    End Try


End Sub
```

It work on VB.NET2010